# iOS Cocoa NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, cocoa

I am trying to determine what is causing this error:

> 2014-06-08 20:40:44.076 Database[8656:70b] -[__NSArrayI length]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a44050

Here is the code.

```
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&error];
```

This is the breaking point where the error occurs: `NSLog([json allKeys]);`

SAMPLE OF THE JSON BEING USED AS INPUT:

```
{"1":{"key":"1","contentONE":"aaa","contentTWO":"testing"},"2":{"key":"2","contentONE":"bbb","contentTWO":null},"3":{"key":"3","contentONE":"ccc","contentTWO":"testing"}}
```

Comment: Check if your "json" dictionary is not nil and also try to NSLog("%@", json); to see the structure of the returned data.

Comment: Looks like it's got an array that it thinks is a string. Length is a string method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[json allKeys]` returns an `NSArray`, while `NSLog` expects a formatting string. Try this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [json allKeys]);
```

Comment: I am sorry to see somebody downvoted an honest question, but I am extremely grateful for your correct answer. Thank you very much!